# Extract values from each region of a venn diagram

Tags: r, bioinformatics, venn-diagram, rna-seq, venn

[image]

I have 6 lists. Each contains genes of interest from a given condition. These six lists were then used to make a venn diagram in r using the venn package.

The venn diagram is precisely what I want, but now I would like to produce a list of genes from each section of the venn diagram. how do I do this? i.e. how do I figure out what genes from my lists comprise the 1251 genes that are present in each list/condition?

```
library(venn)

venn_list_no <- list(pt_v_lb = rownames(pt_v_lb_no), lbdm_v_lb = rownames(lbdm_v_lb_no), ptdm_v_lb = rownames(ptdm_v_lb_no), lbdm_v_pt = rownames(lbdm_v_pt_no), ptdm_v_pt = rownames(ptdm_v_pt_no), ptdm_v_lbdm = rownames(ptdm_v_lbdm_no))

venn(venn_list_no, zcolor = "style", ggplot = T, opacity = 0.2, box = F)+
  theme()
```

Comment: `dput(data)` that would be helpful for replicating the same what your code shows

Comment: I am unsure what dput(data) means. If you are wanting the data from the lists, I am unsure how to upload the list data.

Comment: See here on how to make a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a look at the package source and I cannot see any documented function to extract the elements in a region. In fact, the `venn` function does not return anything, so there is nothing you can check.
You might want to try my `nVennR` package for that. At this time it is not available in CRAN, but you can install it from Github with `devtools::install_github("vqf/nVennR")`. An example:

```
>library(nVennR)
>myV <- plotVenn(list(set1=c(1, 2, 3), set2=c(2, 3, 4), set3=c(3, 4, 5, 'a', 'b'), set4=c(5, 6, 1, 4)))
```

[image]

```
>getVennRegion(myV, c('set2', 'set3', 'set4'))
[1] 4

>getVennRegion(myV, c('set3'))
[1] "a" "b"

>listVennRegions(myV)
$`0, 0, 0, 1 (set4)`
[1] 6

$`0, 0, 1, 0 (set3)`
[1] "a" "b"

$`0, 0, 1, 1 (set3, set4)`
[1] 5

$`0, 1, 1, 1 (set2, set3, set4)`
[1] 4

$`1, 0, 0, 1 (set1, set4)`
[1] 1

$`1, 1, 0, 0 (set1, set2)`
[1] 2

$`1, 1, 1, 0 (set1, set2, set3)`
[1] "3"
```

You can see more examples at the [vignette](https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2022-01-07/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html).